# Can login even if only the password is partially correct?

Tags: php, authentication, hash, salt, bcrypt

I acciedentley stumbled upon a problem with my login form. I seem to be able to login in when the password is partially correct.

If i create the following user:

Username: hehehehehe

Password: hehehehehe

I can login with passwords like "hehehehe", "hehehehehe11111" etc. If i write it completely wrong, it doesn't work.

**Login.php**

```
if (empty($_POST) === false) {

$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);

if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, but we need your username and password.';
} else if ($users->user_exists($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry that username doesn\'t exists.';
// } else if ($users->email_confirmed($username) === false) {
    // $errors[] = 'Sorry, but you need to activate your account. 
                 // Please check your email.';

} else {
    if (strlen($password) > 18) {
        $errors[] = 'The password should be less than 18 characters, without spacing.';
    }
    $login = $users->login($username, $password);
    if ($login === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, that username/password is invalid';
    }else {
        $_SESSION['id'] =  $login;
        header('Location: home.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

}

**User.class.php**

```
public function login($username, $password) {

    global $bcrypt;

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `password`, `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $username);

    try{

        $query->execute();
        $data               = $query->fetch();
        $stored_password    = $data['password']; 
        $id                 = $data['user_id']; 

        if($bcrypt->verify($password, $stored_password) === true){ 
            return $id;
        }else{
            return false;   
        }

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

**Bcrypt.class.php**

```
class Bcrypt {
private $rounds;
public function __construct($rounds = 12) {
    if(CRYPT_BLOWFISH != 1) {
        throw new Exception("Bcrypt is not supported on this server, please see the following to learn more: http://php.net/crypt");
    }
    $this->rounds = $rounds;
}

private function genSalt() {

    $string = str_shuffle(mt_rand());
    $salt   = uniqid($string ,true);

    return $salt;
}


public function genHash($password) {

    $hash = crypt($password, '$2y$' . $this->rounds . '$' . $this->genSalt());
    return $hash;
}


public function verify($password, $existingHash) {

    $hash = crypt($password, $existingHash);


    if($hash === $existingHash) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Any ideas?

If you guys thinks it could do with the registration process, please let me know and i'll upload the register code aswell. What i can't figure out is that why it works even if just parts of the password is correct, I've never experienced that before.

Answer (score 1):

It seems crypt is using DES for hashing rather than blowfish:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

> The standard DES-based crypt() returns the salt as the first two characters of the output. It also only uses the first eight characters of str, so longer strings that start with the same eight characters will generate the same result (when the same salt is used).

Try to login with just the first 8 characters using your code.

Also have a look at the saved hashes stored in your database to see if they're using blowfish or DES. If using blowfish they should have the $2y$ signature you used.

Comment: fleed - That seems to be the problem, yeah. As soon as i surpass 8 charachters for my password i'll get logged in. The hash looks fine in my database, for example. "$2hk6fF3VetiQ".

Comment: @CheesePuffs - This stored hash-value does _not_ look fine. A correct BCrypt value would start with `$2y$`, something must be wrong with your registration process. Also your class `Bcrypt` would fail because of the formatting, if the cost parameter is less than 10. I recommend to use the new PHP function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) or its compatibility pack.